# print url of page using load function to load page inside a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am using following function to load page inside another page. The thing I want is that When inside page load it should change url as well. so if page refresh user stay on same page. Right now when user refresh the page or try to go back it go to parent page.

Here is function.

```
$("#canceledOrders").click(function(){
                $("#pageload").load("canceledOrders.php"); 
            });
```

Html

```
    <li><a id="canceledOrders" href="#!" class="waves-effect">
<i data-icon="F" class="linea-icon linea-ecommerce"></i> 
<span class="hide-menu">Canceled Orders</span></a></li>
```

Now it creates .com/#! If I use some word in href it shows it in url but by refresh page it back to main page again.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

You should use e.preventDefault to avoid the  tag to function as it should by default. Instead, you are going to override it's functionality.

You can do that by modifying the code as such:

```
$("#canceledOrders").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#pageload").load("canceledOrders.php"); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But it did not print url of page. My goal is to print url of page loaded in side so when user refresh page he stay on same page.